# Rails Console not starting up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-console

I am trying to run rails console `rails c` in ConEmu and Cmder but get the following error....

```html
    C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/open-uri.rb:30:in `initialize': No such
 file or directory @ rb_sysopen - C:/Users/user.name/Documents/parentDir/app_dir/log/app_dev.log (Errno::ENOENT)
        from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/open-uri.rb:30:in `open'
        from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/open-uri.rb:30:in `open'
        from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/open-uri.rb:30:in `open'
        from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/logger.rb:600:in `create_l
ogfile'
        from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/logger.rb:594:in `rescue i
n open_logfile'
        from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/logger.rb:591:in `open_log
file'
        from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/logger.rb:549:in `initiali
ze'
        from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/logger.rb:318:in `new'
        from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/logger.rb:318:in `initiali
ze'
        from C:/Users/user.name/Documents/parentDir/app_dir/config/environments/development.rb:57:in `new'
        from C:/Users/user.name/Documents/parentDir/app_dir/config/environments/development.rb:57:in `block in <top (require
d)>'
        from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.9/l
ib/rails/railtie.rb:210:in `instance_eval'
        from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.9/l
ib/rails/railtie.rb:210:in `configure'
        from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.9/l
ib/rails/railtie.rb:182:in `configure'
        from C:/Users/user.name/Documents/parentDir/app_dir/config/environments/development.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.
1.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.
1.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
        from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.
1.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
        from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.
1.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.9/l
ib/rails/engine.rb:594:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
        from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.9/l
ib/rails/engine.rb:593:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.9/l
ib/rails/engine.rb:593:in `block in <class:Engine>'
        from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.9/l
ib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
        from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.9/l
ib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
        from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.9/l
ib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
        from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:226:in `block in
tsort_each'
        from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:348:in `block (2
levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
        from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:418:in `block (2
levels) in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
        from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:427:in `each_stro
ngly_connected_component_from'
        from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:417:in `block in
each_strongly_connected_component_from'
        from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.9/l
ib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.9/l
ib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child'
        from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:411:in `call'
        from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:411:in `each_stro
ngly_connected_component_from'
        from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:347:in `block in
each_strongly_connected_component'
        from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `call'
        from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each_stro
ngly_connected_component'
        from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:224:in `tsort_eac
h'
        from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_eac
h'
        from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.9/l
ib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
        from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.9/l
ib/rails/application.rb:300:in `initialize!'
        from C:/Users/user.name/Documents/parentDir/app_dir/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.
1.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.
1.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
        from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.
1.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
        from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.
1.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.9/l
ib/rails/application.rb:276:in `require_environment!'
        from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.9/l
ib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:147:in `require_application_and_
environment!'
        from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.9/l
ib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in `console'
        from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.9/l
ib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
        from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.9/l
ib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

I can run rails console in the terminal on RubyMine but that is the most useless terminal ever to exist. Any idea what might be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It says that `log/app_dev.log` file is missing - try to create it in the app directory and see what happens.

Comment: thank you! For months I never understood the error because on RubyMine I had `log/app_dev.log` but it was never added so it never appeared in my local directories.